# Php CURL Post , data is not sent

Tags: php, post, curl

i can use Ajax to POST to a php file i have in my site but when i try to post to the same php file using php,  my server doesn't seem to get any data and it will not post
this is the msg i get in the server logs : 
"POST /login_exec.php HTTP/1.0" 302 447 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)" 
i tryed lots of different curl scripts but i can't seem to find why its not working.
this is the code i currently use - (i tryed lots of different options)

```
     <?php

//create array of data to be posted
$post_data['username'] = 'yarden';
$post_data['password'] = 'yarden';

//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
$post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}

//create the final string to be posted using implode()
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = curl_init('http://mydomain.org.il/login_exec.php');

//set options
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

//set data to be posted
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);

//show information regarding the request
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . curl_error($curl_connection);

//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);

?>
```

sorry for my english, and please help me : ) 
thanks

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` is missing, Yarden

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `302` is a redirect status code.

Add **`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true`** to your array

```
$curlConfig = array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => "http://mydomain.org.il/login_exec.php",
        CURLOPT_POST           => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
            'username' => 'yarden',
            'password' => 'yarden',
        ),
    );
```

Comment: hi and thanks for the quick reply,i edited the code in my main post to the code i use . your answer doesn't seem to work ; the error in the server is 302 447 now